# How can I put CSV files in a array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

So I need to put the content of some of the columns of  a CSV file into a array so I can operate with them. 
My File looks like this:

```
userID,placeID,rating,food_rating,service_rating
U1077,135085,2,2,2
U1077,135038,2,2,1
U1077,132825,2,2,2
U1077,135060,1,2,2
U1068,135104,1,1,2
U1068,132740,0,0,0
U1068,132663,1,1,1
U1068,132732,0,0,0
U1068,132630,1,1,1
U1067,132584,2,2,2
U1067,132733,1,1,1
U1067,132732,1,2,2
U1067,132630,1,0,1
U1067,135104,0,0,0
U1067,132560,1,0,0
U1103,132584,1,2,1
U1103,132732,0,0,2
U1103,132630,1,2,0
U1103,132613,2,2,2
U1103,132667,1,2,2
U1103,135104,1,2,0
U1103,132663,1,0,2
U1103,132733,2,2,2
U1107,132660,2,2,1
U1107,132584,2,2,2
U1107,132733,2,2,2
U1044,135088,2,2,2
U1044,132583,1,2,1
U1070,132608,2,2,1
U1070,132609,1,1,1
U1070,132613,1,1,0
U1031,132663,0,0,0
U1031,132665,0,0,0
U1031,132668,0,0,0
U1082,132630,1,1,1
```

and I want to get the PlaceID and save it in a array and in same position also put the ratings. What I need to do is get a average rating of every PlaceID.

I have been trying something like

```
cut -d"," -f2  FileName >> var[@]
```

Comment: It's not impossible with bash but I would use awk to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to accomplish in bash but pretty strightforward in awk:

`awk -F',' 'NR>1 {sum[$2] += $3; count[$2]++}; END{ for (id in sum) { print id, sum[id]/count[id] } }' file.csv`

Explanation: -F set's the field separator and you want filed 2 and the average of field 3. At the end we print the unique ids and the average. We work on all rows but the first one (row number over 1).

Comment: I suggest changing `/^ U*/` to `NR>1`, you don't need pattern matching in this case.

Comment: Thanks @oguzismail

Comment: well the thing is, this is something i have to do for my class and they dont want the awk, and that mess me up quite a bit.